# Converting a loop into a list comprehension to get IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, indexing, list-comprehension, tokenize

I would like to understand how a list comprehension would work here.

I have this loop and it works.

```
    token = nltk.word_tokenize(doc)
    # add parts of speech to token
    pos = nltk.pos_tag(token)
    nsets = []
    for w, p in pos:
        s = wn.synsets(w, convert_tag(p))
        if s:
            nsets.append(s[0])
        else:
            continue
```

however, when I try to do a list comprehension like this

```
nsets = [s[0] for w, p in pos if s == wn.synsets(w, convert_tag(p))]
```

I get

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-406837792edd> in <module>()
----> 1 doc_to_synsets('Tom loves to play petanque')

<ipython-input-25-1eca09bded8e> in doc_to_synsets(doc)
     44             continue
     45 
---> 46     nsets = [s[0] for w, p in pos if s == wn.synsets(w, convert_tag(p))]
     47 
     48     nltk2wordnet = [(i[0], convert_tag(i[1])) for i in pos]

<ipython-input-25-1eca09bded8e> in <listcomp>(.0)
     44             continue
     45 
---> 46     nsets = [s[0] for w, p in pos if s == wn.synsets(w, convert_tag(p))]
     47 
     48     nltk2wordnet = [(i[0], convert_tag(i[1])) for i in pos]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

I have tried to add len(s[0])>0 and len(s)> at the end of the list comrehension like I have seen in similar questions but it did not help..
thank you.

Comment: When converting it, you never initialize ```s```. So that's what you are getting the error on.

Comment: No, it does not work even if I add s = wn.synsets(w, convert_tag(p)) before[...]. you can run my code.

Comment: Yea when you add it like that it messes up the syntax. I'm just telling you what is broken. Btw, the fix is not to use s at all if you want to use list comprehension. Think of it like this, how would you get rid of s in the original code?

Comment: so is it just like this? nsets = [(w, convert_tag(p))[0] for w, p in pos]

Comment: how simple! I am glad you've given me a hint instead of a direct answer. thank you

Comment: Glad that could help. For me it helps to figure out the issue that was broken, so that's why I was trying to point you at things to look at for what was broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you absolutely want to use list comprehension here.
You need to fix how `s` is never declared. There's also no good way to declare `s` in this instance, so you have to call `wn.synsets(w, convert_tag(p))` twice.

```
synsets = [wn.synsets(w, convert_tag(p))[0] for w, p in pos if wn.synsets(w, convert_tag(p))]
```

But since you are calling that same function twice, the list comprehension is going to be slower than the original code.

The question becomes, do you want to save memory by never declaring `s` or do you want faster code by only having to run `wn.synsets(w, convert_tag(p))` one time?
Usually in the grand scheme of things, the single extra temporary variable is the better option as that has a defined footprint where as the double function call will have a exponential scale to it.

Comment: OK, because the loop and the list comprehension were giving me different answers.. the should be this [Synset('tom.n.01'), Synset('love.v.01'), Synset('play.v.01')]  to 'Tom loves to play petanque'.

Answer (score 1):

All Lists Indexing Begin With 0, So If You Have 23 Items In A List, Your Last Item Is Item # 22.

Answer (score 1):

Since `Python 3.8`, you can use walrus operator (`:=`):

```py
nsets = [s[0] for w, p in pos if (s := wn.synsets(w, convert_tag(p)))]
```

Comment: huh, it does look like a walrus! :O )